# Filter users by roles

Tags: views, users

I've a page showing the users. I wanted to categorized them, so I created roles and I'm grouping all the users according to their role. 
Now, I want to have a filter in the view to give the opportunity to the users to select the different types of users, example: employee, student, etc. The view will display the users according to the filter value.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the view ***People (User) view***, which is located at relative path `/admin/structure/views/view/user_admin_people`.

This view has a ***User role exposed filter***. You only need to implement the same filter in your view.

You need to select the same filter in screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Much better! Please review my additional edit I applied, trying to further improve your answer. Feel free to further correct if needed, or just perform a rolback if you do't ike my edit at all.

Comment: thank you! However, I cannot replicate 100% the same filter. it seems that page has the is one of operator and my page doesn't have that option. I've is equal to. Any idea how I can replicate this?

Comment: @valentina-rodriguez I've update my answer, check the screenshot attached, to replicate the filter 100%.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there any way to hide the Administrator role?

Comment: @valentina-rodriguez Yes you can by edit the filter and select the roles and enable the 'Limit list to selected items' option.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can do it more user friendly? Is there any module to use? Or should I create a specific styles for this?

Answer (score 1):

In FILTER CRITERIA click Add

[image]

Add **User: Roles** and expose the filter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information, But the thing is I need a filter list and I only have a text box

Comment: @ValentinaRodriguez can you add to your question a screenshot of your filter settings? (like the one I have in my answer).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when I tried to show the users in another view. I cannot generate the users list.

Comment: @ValentinaRodriguez you need to add relationship, something like content author.

Comment: I added a relationship and I added a filter using this field. However, It's still not working. It's only showing a field, but the main problem is that the filter is not working. A username is preload by default and when I clicked on Apply is not showing any information even though I've content matching the filter.

Comment: @ValentinaRodriguez that's a head-scratcher.